# Group of 28 divided into 4 teams, probability of at least 1 girl on each team when there are 7 girls.

Tags: probability

Hello we had a group divided into 4 teams of 7 each and there is a girl on each team. One of the girls thinks there was foul play in choosing the teams so I thought I'd calculate the chance of a girl on each team. This proved to be harder than I expected so I'm asking for help.

I think that since there are 28 total and 7 girls that we would have $\binom{28}{7}\binom{21}{7}\binom{14}{7}$ ways to assign the people to labelled teams.

I think now I would need to count the number of ways girls could be on teams and then divide?

I am unsure if I am doing anything correctly at this point, been years since I took math.

Comment: Since boys:girls = 21:7 = 3:1, a fair team should have 75% boys and 25% girls.

Comment: Observe that there are $4^7$ ways of assigning seven girls to four teams without restriction.  You want to subtract from that the number of ways that at least one of the four teams has no girls.  To do so, you can use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: @rsadhvika what does that have to do with the question asked?

Comment: Although out of curiosity with does the girl think it was unfair.  You can't have more than one girl on every team (because you have fewer than 8 girls total) so at least one team will have to have at most one girl.  What was she expecting.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig: There are $4^7$ ways of assigning the seven girls to the $4$ teams, but those $4^7$ assignments are not equally likely.

Comment: @fleablood: Your second comment is along the same lines as rsadhvika's comment. As rsadhvika observed, on average, a team should be $25$% girls, so an average of $1.75$ girls per team. Hence it's not surprising for it to be the case that each team has at least one girl.

Comment: Which is why it is odd that the girl thought it was unfair.  Usually they'd thing it was unfair if a team has too  many or too few girls. At least one girl on all four teams is neither too few or too many.  Was it that one team had four girls and the rest had one?

Comment: @fleablood: The teams ended up being 3 girls on team A, 1 on team B, 2 on team C, and 1 on team D. I think she may have been upset that she was on a team with 6 guys where another team had 3 girls. Based on all the answers here I feel that it is safe to conclude that there was no foul play and that is just how the randomness played out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Label the teams as $1,2,3,4$.

The total number of ways to form the $4$ teams is
$$
n
=
\binom{28}{7}
\binom{21}{7}
\binom{14}{7}
\binom{7}{7}
$$
Let $v$ be the list of counts, sorted in ascending order, for the number of girls on each of the $4$ teams.

Consider $3$ cases .  . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;v=[1,1,1,4]$.

For case $(1)$, the number of ways to form the $4$ teams is
$$
x_1
=
\left(\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{7}{4}\binom{21}{3}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{3}{1}\binom{18}{6}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{2}{1}\binom{12}{6}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{6}\right)
$$
hence the probability for case $(1)$ is
\begin{align*}
p_1&=\frac{x_1}{n}\\[4pt]
&={\Large{\frac
{
\left(\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{7}{4}\binom{21}{3}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{3}{1}\binom{18}{6}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{2}{1}\binom{12}{6}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{6}\right)
}
{
\binom{28}{7}
\binom{21}{7}
\binom{14}{7}
\binom{7}{7}
}}}
\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2401}{59202}\approx .04055606230\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

**Case $(2)$:**$\;v=[1,1,2,3]$.

For case $(2)$, the number of ways to form the $4$ teams is
$$
x_2
=
\left(\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{7}{3}\binom{21}{4}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{4}{2}\binom{17}{5}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{2}{1}\binom{12}{6}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{6}\right)
$$
hence the probability for case $(2)$ is
\begin{align*}
p_2&=\frac{x_2}{n}\\[4pt]
&={\Large{\frac
{
\left(\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{7}{3}\binom{21}{4}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{4}{2}\binom{17}{5}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{2}{1}\binom{12}{6}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{6}\right)
}
{
\binom{28}{7}
\binom{21}{7}
\binom{14}{7}
\binom{7}{7}
}}}
\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2401}{6578}\approx .3650045607\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

**Case $(3)$:**$\;v=[1,2,2,2]$.

For case $(3)$, the number of ways to form the $4$ teams is
$$
x_3
=
\left(\binom{4}{3}\binom{1}{1}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{7}{2}\binom{21}{5}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{5}{2}\binom{16}{5}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{3}{2}\binom{11}{5}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{6}\right)
$$
hence the probability for case $(3)$ is
\begin{align*}
p_3&=\frac{x_3}{n}\\[4pt]
&={\Large{\frac
{
\left(\binom{4}{3}\binom{1}{1}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{7}{2}\binom{21}{5}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{5}{2}\binom{16}{5}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{3}{2}\binom{11}{5}\right)
{\cdot}
\left(\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{6}\right)
}
{
\binom{28}{7}
\binom{21}{7}
\binom{14}{7}
\binom{7}{7}
}}}
\\[4pt]
&=\frac{7203}{32890}\approx .2190027364\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Hence the probability that each team has at least one girl is
$$
p
=
p_1+p_2+p_3
=
\frac{2401}{59202}
+
\frac{2401}{6578}
+
\frac{7203}{32890}
=
\frac{16807}{26910}\approx .6245633593
$$

Comment: Wow! Now that you've done it, it almost looks obvious to split it out into the 3 different possibilities for teams and add the probabilities together. We did end up having the girls split like case 2 which looks to be the most probable outcome. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

You only need consider ways to arrange the *7 girls* among *28 places* (4 teams of 7 places each), and use the principle of inclusion and exclusion to count ways that some teams have no girls.
$$\mathsf P(\text{no team has no girls})=1- \dfrac{{\dbinom 41\dbinom{21}7}-{\dbinom42\dbinom{14}7}+{\dbinom 43\dbinom 77}}{\dbinom{28}7}=\dfrac{16807}{26910}$$

---

Remark: How does this work?

A method of fairly assigning teams might be to draw names out of a hat, or such lottery, then assign teams based on order of draw.  There are $28!$ ways to do so.

Now this process is equivalent drawing girls and boys from separate hats, with a fair way to select 7 from 28 positions in the draw to come from the girls' hat. We can see that indeed:$$28!=\binom{28}7 7!\,21!$$

So we just need to focus on the selection of those positions.

Okay, there are $\tbinom 41$ ways to select a team to have all boys and $\tbinom {21}7$ ways to select positions among the rest for the girls.  However, this includes cases where two or more teams have all boys, so we use the principle of exclusion and inclusion to avoid overcounting.  Thus the numerator above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It really helped make it click in my head.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a terrible way to do this.

There are $7!$ ways to line up the girls along a wall and $21!$ ways to line up the boys along another wall.  Now we do a single riffle shuffle to mix the girls into the boys without changing the order of the girls or the boys.  We look at the four "packets" of $7$; that is positions $1-7,8-14,15-21,22-28$.

If we add A to J up we get $508,232$

A) One team has seven girls.

All the girls in the same packet.  There are four packets so $4$ ways to do this:  $4$.

Or $0.0008\%$.

B) One team has six girls and one has one girl.

$4$ choices for one packet with six girls. and $3$ choices for one packet with one girl.  ${7 \choose 6}$ choices for the positions of the six girls and ${7\choose 1}$ choices for the position of the one girl:  $4*3*7*7 = 588$.

Or $0.1\%$

C) One team with five girls and one with two girls.

$4*3$ for which two packets to pick.  ${7\choose 5}$ and ${7\choose 2}$ for the positions within the packets.  $12*21*21 = 5292$

Or $1\%$

D) One team with five girls and two teams with one girl.

$4$ choices for the packet with five girls and ${3\choose 2} =3$ choices for the packets with one girl.  ${7\choose 5}$ ways to place the five girls in a packet and ${7\choose 1}$ for each of the two packets with one girl: $4*3*21*7*7= 12348$

$2.5%$

E) One team with four, one with 3.

$4*3*{7\choose 4}{7\choose 3} = 12*35*35= 14,700$.

$2.9\%$

F) One team with four, one with two, one with one.

$4*3*2*{7\choose 4}{7\choose 2}{7\choose 1} = 24*35*21*7=123480$

$24.3\%$.

G) One team with four, three with one.

$4*{7\choose 4}{7\choose 1}{7\choose 1}{7\choose 1} = 1372$

$0.3\%$

H) two teams with $3$, one with one.

${4\choose 2}{2\choose 1}{7\choose 3}{7\choose 3}{7\choose 1} = 6*2*35*35*7 = 102,900$

$20.2\%$

H) one team with $3$, two with two.

$4*3*35*21*21 = 185,220$

$36.4\%$.

I) one team with $3$, one with two, two with one.

$4*3*35*21*7= 61,740$

$12\%$

(According to you comment this is the one that occurred.

J) three teams with $2$, and one with one.

$4*{7\choose 2}^3*{7\choose 1} = 4*21*7 = 588$.

$1.1\%$

Notice this "fairest" of distributions is actually one of the less likely options.  This is not all that unusual.